# Replacing multiple characters in a capturing group

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace the square brackets for curly brackets and the underscores for spaces.

Input:
`[something_id='123'_more-info='321']`

Output so far:
`{something_id='123'_more-info='321'}`

Required Output:
`{something id='123' more-info='321'}`

I can replace the brackets but I don't know where to start with searching within the capturing group to replace the spaces. I'm not even sure what terms I should be searching the web for to try to find the answer.

```
search = re.compile(r"\[(something.*)\]")
return search.sub(r"{\1}", text_source)
```

Comment: First get the content between the square brackets from group 1 using `\[(something[^][]*)]` , and then replace all the spaces for underscores.

Comment: Maybe `f"{{{s.strip('[]').replace('_', ' ')}}}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have these texts inside longer texts, use a callable as the replacement argument to `re.sub`:

```py
import re
text_source = '''Text [something_id='123'_more-info='321'] Text...'''
search = re.compile(r"\[(something[^]]*)]")
print( search.sub(lambda x: f"{{{x.group(1).replace('_', ' ')}}}", text_source) )
# => Text {something id='123' more-info='321'} Text...
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FmoGkC).

**Details**

- `\[(something[^]]*)]` matches `[`, then captures `something` and then zero or more chars other than `]` into Group 1 and then matches `]`
- `lambda x: f"{{{x.group(1).replace('_', ' ')}}}"` - the match is passed to the lambda where Group 1 text is enclosed with curly braces and the underscores are replaced with spaces
- Note that literal curly braces inside f-strings must be doubled.

If the strings are standalone strings, all you need is

```py
text_source = f"{{{text_source.strip('[]').replace('_', ' ')}}}"
```

Comment: Hey Wiktor, thanks for that and especially the explanation. Is there any reason you chose the " [^]]* " rather than the " .* "?

Comment: @alj `[^]]` is a negated character class and will not match more than up to the closest `]`. `.*` is too greedy.